# Angular - How to send component with state to overlay

Tags: angular, overlay

I am trying to take an existing component as is in its current state, and with the DOM, to the overlay. It seems that it wouldn't work when I read the docs b/c a portal has to be created with the component factory with it. My goal is to move the component from a regular page to something that floats in the app while the user is browsing it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How can I send code when I don't know how to do it?